# Html To Pdf conversion in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pdf, html2pdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf. Is there any custom directive, which i can use.I also tried to use angular-save-html-to-pdf from npm site but there is some error while using.
Is there any other way to convert html to css in angular js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library which supports this. It's using html2canvas. There is a [demo](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/) on their site.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PdfMake`](http://pdfmake.org/) with angularjs.

I have made a sample with pdfmake.

```
var docDefinition = {
      content: [
        {
          text: 'Criketers and scores'
        },
        {
          style: 'demoTable',
          table: {
            widths: ['*', '*', '*'],
            body: [
              [{text: 'Name', style: 'header'}, {text: 'Matches', style: 'header'},
                {text: 'Score', style: 'header'}
              ],
              ['Sachin', '344', '52'],
              ['Sanga', '320', '89'],
              ['Ponting', '300', '68'] 
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      styles: {
        header: {
          bold: true,
          color: '#000',
          fontSize: 11
        },
        demoTable: {
          color: '#666',
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.openPdf = function() {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    };

    $scope.downloadPdf = function() {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
    };
```

**[DEMO](https://github.com/sajeetharan/angularPDFgenerator)**